# Updating Jest Snapshot triggers "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I can run my tests fine, until I need to update a snapshot. When I do, it errors.

Test file, first run, snapshot written:

```
import { useIsMobile } from '@hooks';
import {
  createMock as mockCreateMock,
  snapshotOf,
} from 'jest-snapshot-propifier';
import React from 'react';

import { TabBar } from './TabBar';

jest.mock('./Tab.tsx', () => ({ Tab: mockCreateMock('Tab') }));

describe('TabBar', () => {
  it('renders items at full width', () => {
    useIsMobile.mockReturnValueOnce(true);

    expect(snapshotOf(<TabBar items={['Tab 1', 'Tab 2']} />))
      .toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      <div
        aria-label="terms location selector"
        className="container--large wrapper"
        role="tablist"
      >
        <div
          data-component="<Tab />"
          data-is_active={true}
          data-on_click="[! Function to test !]"
          data-title="Tab 1"
        />
        <div
          data-component="<Tab />"
          data-is_active={false}
          data-on_click="[! Function to test !]"
          data-title="Tab 2"
        />
      </div>
    `);
  });
});
```

Then update something to invalidate the snapshot:

```
 ● TabBar › renders items at full width

    expect(received).toMatchInlineSnapshot(snapshot)

    Snapshot name: `TabBar renders items at full width 1`

    - Snapshot  - 1
    + Received  + 1

    @@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
      <div
        aria-label="terms location selector"
    -   className="container--large wrapper"
    +   className="container--full-width wrapper"
```

Then hit <kbd>u</kbd> to update:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (56:3)
      54 | toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      55 | <div
    > 56 |   aria-label="terms location selector"
         |   ^
      57 |   className="container--large wrapper"
      58 |   role="tablist"
      59 | >

      at p (node_modules/prettier/parser-babel.js:22:1054)
      at d (node_modules/prettier/parser-babel.js:22:1287)
      at Object.parse (node_modules/prettier/parser-babel.js:29:54501)
      at Object.parse (node_modules/prettier/index.js:7515:23)
      at coreFormat (node_modules/prettier/index.js:8829:18)
      at formatWithCursor2 (node_modules/prettier/index.js:9021:18)
      at node_modules/prettier/index.js:38183:12
      at Object.format (node_modules/prettier/index.js:38197:12)
```

My config file:

```
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */

const config = {
  bail: 5,
  clearMocks: true,
  coverageDirectory: '.coverage',
  coverageReporters: [
    'json',
    'lcov',
    'text',
    ['text', { file: 'coverage.txt', path: './.coverage' }],
  ],
  coverageProvider: 'v8', //istanbul clashes with Cypress
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '<rootDir>/app/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  //coverageThreshold
  errorOnDeprecated: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(scss|css|less)$': '<rootDir>/jest/scss.js',
    '@constants': '<rootDir>/app/constants',
    '^swiper/css': '<rootDir>/jest/scss.js',
  },
  randomize: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest/jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec).[jt]s?(x)'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
    '<rootDir>/cypress/',
    '<rootDir>/.next/',
    '<rootDir>/coverage/',
    '<rootDir>/jest/',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': ['babel-jest', { configFile: './jest/babel.config.js' }],
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': '@swc/jest',
  },
  verbose: true,
};

module.exports = config;
```